# Entity framework code first circular reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, automapper

I want an object to reference itself. How do I write this model? For eg.

```
public class Term
{
    public int TermId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Term PreviousTerm { get; set; }
    public virtual int? PreviousTermId { get; set; }
}
```

The schema generated is:

```
TermId
Name
PreviousTermId
PreviousTerm_TermId
```

So apparently, `PreviousTermId` serves no purpose here as a relationship FK.

But when using automapper, I have to map to `PreviousTermId`, I cant create the new object `PreviousTerm` and assign the Id to that. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying  the mappings in onModel `OnModelCreating` event

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {             
            modelBuilder.Entity<Term>().HasOptional(t =>t.PreviousTerm).WithMany().
                           HasForeignKey(t=>t.PreviousTermId);  
       }
```